# AppDelegate, Thread 1: signal SIGABRT (11db), without IB outlets

Tags: swift, xcode8, appdelegate, sigabrt

I've been researching on forums, here, and youtube for answers but non have been to an avail. I've found after implementing this code I've been getting the error. Thank you. This is Xcode 8, swift; and here is the specific code and console error:

```
func startNewLevel1() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run(spawnBubble)
    let waitToSPawn = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, waitToSPawn])
    let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence)
    self.run(spawnForever)

}
```

ibc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

**EDIT**

```
 func spawnBubble(){

    let randomXStart = random(min: gameArea.minX, max: gameArea.maxX)
    let randomYEnd = random(min: gameArea.minY, max: gameArea.maxY)

    let spawnPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: randomYEnd)

    bubble.position = spawnPoint
    bubble.zPosition = 1
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let scale = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600), duration: 5.0)
        bubble.run(scale)

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    // bubble.run(scale)
    bubble.name = "circle"
    bubble.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    self.addChild(bubble)

}
```

Comment: Did you put `func` before `startNewlevel1()`?

Comment: Also what is `spawnBubble`? I would bet that has to do with the bug. One way to tell is set a breakpoint right where the method starts, and then walk through it to see which line causes the crash. That way you can narrow it down to one specific line of code.

Comment: yeah, when I copied the code I accidentally cut it out

Comment: spawnBubble is another function, it works without startNewLevel1

Comment: Would you mind pasting the `spawnBubble` method? Because I can't see anything wrong with your code. If I make a dummy SpriteKit app that uses it, it works fine.

Comment: So I think part of the problem is that you keep running this `spawnBubble` method, which never actually seems to create a new `bubble` sprite. You keep trying to re-add a sprite to your scene that's already added

Comment: Does the sprite have to be deleted before a new one can be added? Also, could the zPosition cause the error? @Pierce

Comment: The z-position is more or less just a hierarchy control, that shouldn't cause your problem. I wouldn't say it has to be deleted, but if all you want to do is move it, just change it's position, don't go through the trouble of adding and re-creating it. If you do want to use the same one, add it, and then call `removeFromParent()` on the sprite to make sure it's removed from the scene, then re-add it. I would however recommend just instantiating a whole new bubble sprite each time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135476/discussion-between-patrick-j-and-pierce).